# htpasswd keeps asking for password - phpmyadmin

Tags: .htaccess, phpmyadmin, .htpasswd

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop to host an apache2 webserver. I installed phpmyadmin and wanted to secure it using htpasswd. There for I edited the `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`, adding `AllowOverride All` and restarted apache2. I checked the conf-enabled folder and saw that that had updated too. Then I created a `.htaccess` file in the `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` folder(the folder `phpmyadmin.conf` was referring to. I put this in the `.htaccess` file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "PHPMyAdmin for servername."
AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Next, I created a `.htpasswd` file:

```
htpasswd -c /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd admin
```

Last I restarted apache2:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

I made sure that the `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` file were where I put them.

**Most importantly:**

> I have looked up answers for similar problems but none of the solutions work for me!

**Edit:** Problem solved. Solution: be better at remembering which passwords are used for which accounts

Comment: Check your logs. Tell us what you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I just tried restarting apache2 over and over again and I'm not sure what log you are talking about and where to find it

Comment: The logs are wherever you configured them to be. If you didn't change the configuration, try looking in `/var/log/apache2` which seems to be the directory Ubuntu wants to put them in. As for restarting over and over again, is that all you did? Your question certainly implied that you tried other things, but you weren't specific, and you need to be specific.

Comment: I looked at error.log and 'password mismatch' seems to be the problem.

Comment: I was thinking of another password, how silly!